# How I add extra table under the third mainpanel to shiny app

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity

I have put together a shiny app. Now, I need to add another panel to that but by simply adding extra mainplanel to the code, my other two panels being deactivated

This is my app

```
navbarPageWithText <- function(..., text) {

  navbar <- navbarPage(...)

  textEl <- tags$p(class = "navbar-text", text)

  navbar[[3]][[1]]$children[[1]] <- htmltools::tagAppendChild(

    navbar[[3]][[1]]$children[[1]], textEl)

  navbar

}



# Call this function with an input (such as `textInput("text", NULL, "Search")`) if you

# want to add an input to the navbar

navbarPageWithInputs <- function(..., inputs) {

  navbar <- navbarPage(...)

  form <- tags$form(class = "navbar-form", inputs)

  navbar[[3]][[1]]$children[[1]] <- htmltools::tagAppendChild(

    navbar[[3]][[1]]$children[[1]], form)

  navbar

}
library(shiny)
library(DT)
Patient_005=as.data.frame(read.table(text = "   Driver  SNV_Tumour_005  SNV_Organoid_005    INDEL_Tumour_005    INDEL_Organoid_005  Deletion_Organoid_005
                                     ABCB1   *   *   *   -   -   -
                                     ACVR1B  *   *   -   -   -   -
                                     ACVR2A  *   -   -   -   -   -

                                     "))

Patient_013=as.data.frame(read.table(text = "   Driver  SNV_Tumour_013  SNV_Organoid_013    INDEL_Tumour_013    INDEL_Organoid_013  Deletion_Tumour_013 Deletion_Organoid_013
                                     ABCB1   *   -   *   -   -   -   -
                                     ACVR1B  *   -   -   -   -   -   -
                                     ACVR2A  *   -   -   -   -   -   -

                                     "))

Patient_036 = as.data.frame(read.table(text = " Driver  SNV_Organoid_036    INDEL_Organoid_036  Deletion_Organoid_036
                                       ABCB1   *   -   *   -
                                       ACVR1B  *   *   *   -
                                       ACVR2A  *   *   -   -

                                       "))

Patient_021 = as.data.frame(read.table(text = " Driver  SNV_Organoid_021    INDEL_Organoid_021
                                       ABCB1   *   *   -
                                       ACVR1B  *   *   -
                                       ACVR2A  *   *   *

                                       "))

ui <- shinyUI(navbarPage("Patients",
                         tabPanel("Table",theme = "bootstrap.css",

                                  headerPanel("Genomic variations in OESO driver genes"),

                                  sidebarPanel(br(),
                                               tags$style("#select1 {border: 2px solid #dd4b39;}"), div(

                                                 id = "loading-content",

                                                 h2("Binary output"), navbarPageWithText(

                                                   "* means that gene carries an event",

                                                   text = "- means that no event has been observed"

                                                 )

                                               ),
                                               selectInput(
                                                 "table_dataset",
                                                 "Choose patient:",
                                                 choices = c("Patient_005","Patient_013","Patient_036","Patient_021")
                                               ) 
                                  ),
                                  mainPanel(DT::dataTableOutput("table"))
                         ),
                         tabPanel("Image",
                                  sidebarPanel( br(),
                                                tags$style("#select2 {background-color:blue;}"),
                                                selectInput(
                                                  "image_dataset",
                                                  "Choose image:",
                                                  choices = c("Mutational_Signatures"="https://i.ibb.co/hZYc9nM/Mutational-Signatures1.png", "Total_and_Minor_Copy_Number" = "https://i.ibb.co/pRYxfwF/Total-and-Minor-Copy-Number.png", "Structural_Variations" = "https://i.ibb.co/JB4z6y6/Strutural-Variations.png", "Statistics" = "https://i.ibb.co/DYm2nm4/Statistics.png" , "Major_and_Minor_Copy_Number" = "https://i.ibb.co/ZV3DTXN/Major-and-Minor-Copy-Number.png", "Mutational_consequences_SNVs" = "https://i.ibb.co/CpyqRdr/Mutational-consequences.png" , "Mutational_consequences_INDEL" = "https://i.ibb.co/Vt4nwqd/Mutational-consequences-indel.png" , "Segment_mean" = "https://i.ibb.co/Cthk4ZD/Segment-mean.png" , "RNA_seq_Driver_Genes" = "https://i.ibb.co/qr9cvdN/RNA-seq.png"
                                                  )
                                                ) 
                                  ),
                                  mainPanel(
                                    uiOutput("image") 
                                  ), div(

                                    id = "loading-content",

                                    h2("Loading..."), navbarPageWithText(

                                      "Images of",

                                      text = "Organoid models"

                                    )

                                  )
                         ),tags$head(
                           tags$style(type = 'text/css', 
                                      HTML('.navbar { background-color: skin-blue;}
                          .navbar-default .navbar-brand{color: black;}
                          .tab-panel{ background-color: skin-blue; color: black}
                          .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, 
                           .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus, 
                           .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover {
                                color: #555;
                                background-color: pink;
                            }')
                           )
                         )
))

server <- function(input, output) {

  # Related to displaying tables
  table_data <- reactive({
    switch(input$table_dataset, "Patient_005" = Patient_005 ,"Patient_013" = Patient_013,"Patient_036" = Patient_036,"Patient_021" = Patient_021)
  })

  column_data <- reactive({
    switch(input$table_dataset, 
           "Patient_005" = c('Driver','SNV_Tumour_005','SNV_Organoid_005','INDEL_Tumour_005','INDEL_Organoid_005','Deletion_Organoid_005'),
           "Patient_013" = c('SNV_Tumour_013','SNV_Organoid_013','INDEL_Tumour_013','INDEL_Organoid_013','Deletion_Tumour_013','Deletion_Organoid_013')
                             )
  })

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(table_data()) %>% 
      formatStyle(
        column_data(),
        backgroundColor = styleEqual(c("*", "-"), c('green', 'red'))
      )
  })

  # Related to displaying images
  output$image <- renderUI({
    tags$img(src = input$image_dataset)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

I need to add this table as another panel with the title of MetaData

```
    > head(MetaData)
     Clinical.ID       Barcode WTSI.Model.ID Tissue.Origin
1 OCC/SH/253/S/T 2000003422203 WTSI-OESO_005   Oesophageal
2 OCC/SH/254/S/T    CGAP-A3F3F WTSI-OESO_013   Oesophageal
3 OCC/SH/255/S/T    CGAP-73FED WTSI-OESO_036   Oesophageal
4 OCC/SH/255/S/N    CGAP-70672 WTSI-OESO_037   Oesophageal
  Sample.type
1      Tumour
2      Tumour
3      Tumour
4      Normal
> 



> dput(head(MetaData))
structure(list(Clinical.ID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("OCC/SH/253/S/T", 
"OCC/SH/254/S/T", "OCC/SH/255/S/N", "OCC/SH/255/S/T"), class = "factor"), 
    Barcode = structure(c(1L, 4L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("2000003422203", 
    "CGAP-70672", "CGAP-73FED", "CGAP-A3F3F"), class = "factor"), 
    WTSI.Model.ID = structure(1:4, .Label = c("WTSI-OESO_005", 
    "WTSI-OESO_013", "WTSI-OESO_036", "WTSI-OESO_037"), class = "factor"), 
    Tissue.Origin = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Oesophageal", class = "factor"), 
    Sample.type = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Normal", 
    "Tumour"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
>
```

Could you please give me a hand in adding this table as the third panel to my app?

Comment: That should work better, but that is not what I suggested. (There are some differences between what you copy from the console and what is actually in the data, for example `factor`s versus actual `character` strings. What you see on the console does *not* show this. `dput` does. I often refer to its use as "unambiguous" sample data.)

Comment: Thank you I edited again